# использование тега section

Tags: html5

он связывает содержимое по смыслу, знаю. Можно использовать для верстки комментариев, постов и так далее. Но видел недавно верстку, которая имела примерно следующую структуру:

```
<body>
   <section>
      <div>
         любого рода блок кода
      </div>
      <div>
         любого рода блок кода
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div>
         любого рода блок кода
      </div>
      <div>
         любого рода блок кода
      </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

был сайт магазина, и верстка была вся в section, то есть каждый блок. Есть ли смысл в такой верстке?

Comment: Мне кажется, что вопрос "есть смысл" не имеет смысла :D Если ты о логическом смысле применимости тега, то да, нормальная штука. Если эти дивы будут определять секции для однотипного контента. Тащемта, из блоков `div` и `section` можно верстать что угодно. ВКонтакте весь из дивов свёрстан - и ещё не развалился вроде бы.

Comment: ну да, подкол оценил)) просто вдруг я новый тренд пропустил, вот и задал вопрос))

Comment: "<section> — смысловой или логический раздел документа;" (источник: https://htmlacademy.ru/courses/73/run/3). Дальше на то вы и верстальщик(если вы верстальщик), что бы осмыслить что куда. Семантика и всё такое...

Comment: @KirillKorushkin я и пытаюсь осмыслить)) всегда думал, что эти теги логично применять только в комментарии, статьи и тп. Но не весь же сайт на них

Comment: Это надо только для поисковых роботов. И злоупотреблять ими не стоит)